# I forgot my default keyring password, how do I get in to recover/change it?

Tags: password-recovery

I forgot my default keyring password, how do I recover/change it?

Answer (score 10):

```
rm /home/$USER/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring
```

will remove the login keyring and ask for a new password.

Or to be a bit safer with a backup:

```
cd /home/$USER/.local/share/keyrings/
cp login.keyring login.keyringOLD
rm login.keyring
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the default_keyring.keyring here or:

```
rm /home/neuron/.local/share/keyrings/Default_keyring.keyring
```

[image: Image of the keyright]